# (Proof verification)An inﬁnite subset of $\Bbb N$ is recursive if and only if it is the range of a strictly increasing recursive function.

Tags: proof-verification, computability, recursion

Given the definition of recursive function as below, I need to prove that:

> An inﬁnite subset of $\Bbb N$ is recursive if and only if it is the range of a strictly increasing recursive function.

[image]

I think to prove **image of increasing recursive function $\implies$ infinite recursive set**, we need to construct a recursive characteristic function for the image of any strictly increasing recursive function.

For strictly increasing recursive function $f$, define function $\chi$ by:

$\chi(x) \ = \ \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } (\exists n\le x)(f(n)=x) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$

$\chi(x)=1$ iff $x$ is in the range of f(x), thus $\chi$ is the characteristic function of the range. As $f$ is strictly increasing and thus injective, its range is an infinite set.

And to prove that **infinite recursive set $\implies$ image of increasing recursive function**, we need to construct a increasing recursive function using the characterist function of the recursive set.

Given an infinite recursive set $A$ its characteristic function $\chi_A$  is a recursive function.

Define function $f$

$f(0)=min_n \lbrace\chi_A(n)=1\rbrace$

$f(n+1)=min_m\lbrace\chi_A(m)=1\land m>f(n)\rbrace$

It is a recursive function.

**In the second direction, I cannot see if there is any usage of the condition: "A" is an infinite set.** So may I ask if that condition is necessary?

May I please ask for checking if the argument above is correct, thanks a lot!